# Deploying .NET application in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have this .NET web forms application which uses SQl server database, It runs fine on local server but as soon as I add windows azure deployment project to it, it is not able to access the database. what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your broad question with a broad answer: have you tried to troubleshoot using the Guidelines for Connecting to SQL Azure Database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx)?